# Custom serialization in Kafka using CSharp

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, apache-kafka, customserializer

I want to write a custom serializer for kafka in CSharp. I've searched a lot and I couldn't find a good reference on how to write custom serializer for kafka in a dotnet language.

Any thoughts on how to write one with dotnet?

Comment: It looks like KafKa is a message broker and doesn't not control the contents of the messages.  Serialization deals with the contents of the messages.  May be you want to send Xml formatted messages and then use Xml Serializer.

Comment: I just find the answer! it is by using the SetValueSerializer and SetKeySerializer in ProducerBuilder class. I will post the answer shortly.

Comment: @jdweng please look at the answer. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The library is just handling the messages, not the contents.  The link is sending as a test message "hello world".  You asked about SERIALZING which is the content of the message.  You do not need to write a custom serializer. Use following and send contents of MemoryStream :             MemoryStream mWriter = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(mWriter);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

Comment: I know how to use existing serializers, my question was on how to develop a "Custom Serializer".

Comment: What are you doing that requires a Custom Serialize?  Why not a regular serialize?

Comment: I'm learning Kafka, I just wanted to know how to do this. I know this is the rather least efficient approach to serialization. There are definitely better options.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Kafka.  You are attempting to send serialized data across a communication path.  So you are just sending characters/bytes over Kafka.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just find the answer to this question.
The library to use for kafka in dotnet is provided by confluent.

[Kafka .NET Client](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/dotnet.html)

There should be a serialization class implementing the interface :

```
Confluent.Kafka.ISerializer<T>
```

Normally we should create the producer via ProducerBuilder class :

```
Confluent.Kafka.ProducerBuilder<TKey, TValue>
```

There is a method to this class to set serializers for both key and value.
It is a little different than the original documentation for custom serializer in Kafka which instructing to set the name of the custom serializer class in the producer configuration.

Following is the code to set the value serializer:

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
    ClientId = "thiPC"
};

var producerBuilder = new ProducerBuilder<Null, Customer>(config);
producerBuilder.SetValueSerializer(new CustomerSerializer());       // <------ The Magic Code
var producer = producerBuilder.Build();
```

The sample code for the Serialization class is like this;

```
public class CustomerSerializer : Confluent.Kafka.ISerializer<Customer>
{
    public byte[] Serialize(Customer data, SerializationContext context)
    { ..........}
}
```

There is nothing important for the Customer class in my example it is a normal class just to hold the customer properties.

In serialization class, you should return a byte[] in the Serialize method which is obvious!

I hope this would be useful for folks implementing Kafka with dotnet.